# PreviewCallback for Camera video

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Can someone provide me the sample code or example for reading each frame of Camera video using PreviewCallback interface?

I want to get the frame without using surface as I want frame of the camera video first without displaying on the screen and then I can pass that frame to the CCLayer of cocos2dx.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slow process and cannot process every frame of data delivered to the preview callback. It should only be used if your requirements for a live preview application make it impossible to display video from the camera or video from the camera with a *stencil* type overlay, and your display can tolerate only a few frames per second with some latency.

**Some important steps**:

1. Your Activity must extend Surface Holder, and you shouldn't  start
   the camera until the surface is created.
2. Preview only supports a specific size on each device (*480 x 320 on the last device I checked - some time ago*), but 
   your request will not cause any problems, it will just get ignored. 
   When you finally do receive the preview callback, check the actual 
   frame size in `onPreviewFrame()`.
3. The `byte[]` array data sent to `onPreviewFrame()` is in YCbCr_422_SP 
   format.  No other formats are available, even if you attempt to set 
   them.  The data is described here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/d3b29d3ddc8abf9b
4. Don't try to decode the data in `onPreviewFrame()`.  There isn't enough 
   time - you will hose the camera if you try to hold up the system in 
   that function for so long.  Copy the data to your own buffer and 
   decode in a separate `Thread`.
5. You will have to skip processing of new frames received while your `Thread` 
   is processing any particular frame. Wait until the `Thread` is finished before 
   using the data from the next available frame.

**Decode the YUV Preview Data**:

```
// decode Y, U, and V values on the YUV 420 buffer 
// described as YCbCr_422_SP by Android - David Manpearl
public static void decodeYUV(int[] out, byte[] fg, int width, int 
height) throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException { 
        final int sz = width * height; 
        if(out == null) throw new NullPointerException("buffer 'out' is null"); 
        if(out.length < sz) throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer 'out' size " + out.length + " < minimum " + sz); 
        if(fg == null) throw new NullPointerException("buffer 'fg' is null"); 
        if(fg.length < sz) throw new IllegalArgumentException("buffer 'fg' size " + fg.length + " < minimum " + sz * 3/ 2); 
        int i, j; 
        int Y, Cr = 0, Cb = 0; 
        for(j = 0; j < height; j++) { 
                int pixPtr = j * width; 
                final int jDiv2 = j >> 1; 
                for(i = 0; i < width; i++) { 
                        Y = fg[pixPtr]; if(Y < 0) Y += 255; 
                        if((i & 0x1) != 1) { 
                                final int cOff = sz + jDiv2 * width + (i >> 1) * 2; 
                                Cb = fg[cOff]; 
                                if(Cb < 0) Cb += 127; else Cb -= 128; 
                                Cr = fg[cOff + 1]; 
                                if(Cr < 0) Cr += 127; else Cr -= 128; 
                        } 
                        int R = Y + Cr + (Cr >> 2) + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 5); 
                        if(R < 0) R = 0; else if(R > 255) R = 255; 
                        int G = Y - (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 4) + (Cb >> 5) - (Cr >> 1) + (Cr >> 3) + (Cr >> 4) + (Cr >> 5); 
                        if(G < 0) G = 0; else if(G > 255) G = 255; 
                        int B = Y + Cb + (Cb >> 1) + (Cb >> 2) + (Cb >> 6); 
                        if(B < 0) B = 0; else if(B > 255) B = 255; 
                        out[pixPtr++] = 0xff000000 + (B << 16) + (G << 8) + R; 
                } 
        } 
}
```

**Convert `byte[]` Array to `Bitmap`**:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(out , 0, out.length);
```

Comment: Can I get the frames without using surface. Actually I want frame first without displaying anything to the surface so that i can send the frame to the CCLayer to display it.